# Why does this php code work fine on the second run while creating a dinamic link from user input?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to create a query screen for reports. I have created a php code by getting support from here and other sites. But the problem is; when a user input report serial number and submits it, the page only reload. After reload; when the user enters serial again to the field and hits submit, this time the code works but only for the 1st serial entered, no matter the second serial is.

I have tried to change the parts of my code but could not find a solution.

I am trying to create a system like, user will enter a serial to the field and when hits to submit button; a new window pop out and directs user to a link which has been created based on user input.

For example, user entered "234" as the serial number and hit submit button. The new window will go to the; "example.com/reports/report234.pdf"

Here is the code I have problem with;

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $seri = $_POST['seri'];
    $url = "https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/Rapor/".$seri.".pdf";    
}
?>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $url; ?>">
    <input type="text" name="seri"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sorgula"><br>
</form>
```

Comment: Because on the first run `$url` is not set. If you had turn on error reporting you would've seen a undefined variable notice.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Do you know how can I turn this code into something I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you're setting the redirect `$url` as the form action. That results in the following:

1. Form action is empty, thus the form will be sent to the page itself
2. The serial number and the `$url` is created and set as the form action
3. **Now** when the user submits the form again it will be directed to the `$url` set, regardless of what he has filled in the `seri` field this time

Here is an example of a more correct approach to your problem:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $seri = $_POST['seri'];
    Header("Location: https://www.ozguncicek.com.tr/wp-content/uploads/Rapor/$seri.pdf");
}
?>
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="seri"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sorgula"><br>
</form>
```

Note there's no need to set an action to the form since you're going to redirect the user when he submits the form.

Another important point is checking if `seri` isn't empty before redirecting the user. That could be accomplished as simple as:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['seri'])
```

Comment: thank you very much, this has completely solved my problem. and plus, I have learned a new thing with it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Redirect after form submit,

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $seri = $_POST['seri'];
    $url = "https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/Rapor/".$seri.".pdf";     
    header("Location: ".$url);   
}
?>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $url; ?>">
    <input type="text" name="seri"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sorgula"><br>
</form>
```